# Start and Follow Patterns For SharePoint 4.0 Connector

Tags: google-search-appliance

I am trying to get the SharePoint 4.0.4 Connector to crawl only some sites in SharePoint.  All the sites are in the same web application.  I just want to crawl some sites but not others.

So for example, let's say my SharePoint web application is at https://sharepoint1.mysite.com.  Then say I have 3 sites: https://sharepoint1.mysite.com/sites/a, https://sharepoint1.mysite.com/sites/b and https://sharepoint1.mysite.com/sites/c.

What start and follow patterns would I use to only crawl https://sharepoint1.mysite.com/sites/a and https://sharepoint1.mysite.com/sites/b?  I do not want to traverse or index https://sharepoint1.mysite.com/sites/c.

My connector is running on a server called connector.mysite.com on port 4040.

I cannot find any documentation that explains setting up patterns for the SharePoint 4.0 Connector.  I already have the installation guide but it doesn't discuss crawling at all.  If you have some documentation, please send it my way.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If you're running a 4.0 connector, by default you have to specify at least the following Follow Pattern:

```
http://connector.mysite.com:4040/doc/
```

Your best bet is to run the connector with that pattern in order to crawl and index some folders from your Sharepoint-repo, after which you can see in Index Diagnostics the correct paths which the connector constructs. After that you can alter your Follow Patterns with the right one. Obviously, you can find information about deploying the connector from the following URL: http://static.googleusercontent.com/media/www.google.com/nl//support/enterprise/static/gsa/docs/admin/connectors/40/404/DeployingtheConnectorforSharePoint.pdf

Pay special attention to chapter **"Deploy the Connector for SharePoint"**. Good luck!